# How to create multi checkboxes and attach them to controller action like Edit or Delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a scaffold Phone and index.html.erb shows a simple table with list of phone and edit/delete options. Now i want to add jquery checkboxes so I can do bulk delete or move actions. See attached image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZXV4.png)

Can someone give me any idea/pointers on how to do it ?

Edit - this is the index.html.erb file

```
<% @phones.each do |phone| %>
  <tr> 
    <td><%= phone.model %></td -->
    <td><%= phone.type %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

there is no form here so I am not sure I can use form_tag helpers or am I confusing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Just a simple form and controller action that iterates through your selected items and destroys them. Do you have any code? Do you mean that you want to use AJAX as this can be done without JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a starting point, a form with the check boxes.

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "phone", :action => "bulk_update", :method => "PUT") %>
 <%= check_box_tag(:blackberry) %>
 <%= label_tag(:pet_dog, "Blackberry") %>
 <%= check_box_tag(:Nokia) %>
 <%= label_tag(:pet_cat, "Nokia") %>
 <%= submit_tag("Update") %>
<% end %>
```

Then a controller action called bulk_update and you could delete/update the records based on what has been submitted.

EDIT: You will also want to create a route in routes.rb for this.

Comment: cih, I have added the code of index.html.erb, unfortunately I am not able to understand what the above code is doing, can you clarify it little more ? thanks

Comment: This is using rails form helpers, they are used to generate the HTML, if you view the source of your index page when you view in the browser you will see the HTML that has been generated. When you click submit it will send a PUT request to your phone controller. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the table in a form helper.

```
<%= form_tag foo_path do %>
  # ...
  <% @phones.each do |phone| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "selected[]", phone.id %></td>
      <td><%= phone.model %></td>
      <td><%= phone.type %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  # ...

  <%= button_tag "Do something" %>
<% end %>
```

This creates a form, with a checkbox in every row of the table. Replace `foo_path` with the route helper that you want to use. The value of the selected checkboxes will be passed to your controller action in the array `params[:selected]`, where you can do with them as you wish. The values of each checkbox will be the `id` for the corresponding `phone` object.